# Python, Store specific words to varibles in input

Tags: python

The title says it all. Is there a way so I input

```
input("")
```

They input

```
dbs -U thebos123 -P pw.txt
```

Then store **thebos123** into a variable but not the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always the third word, you can get it this way.

```
line = raw_input("Some input please: ")  # or `input("Some...` in python 3
splitline = line.split(" ");
var = splitline[2]
print var
```

Test

```
python pyprog.py 
Some input please: dbs -U thebos123 -P pw.txt
thebos123
```